# Slice a Pandas Dataframe according to the percentage of a column category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to slice the dataframe according to the percentage of category in a column of the dataset. If I have a datframe something like this

```
>> age  height weight obese
   28    6.7   82      0
   22    5.10  67      0
   18    6     77      0
   19    5.2   88      1
   21    5.3   89      1
   24    5.9   68      0
```

I would like to slice the data based on the obese column with its category percentage. For example:

```
>> df_equal
   age  height weight obese
   28    6.7   82      0
   21    5.3   89      1

>> df_minority
   age  height weight obese
   28    6.7   82      0
   19    5.2   88      1
   21    5.3   89      1

>> df_majority
   age  height weight obese
   28    6.7   82      0
   22    5.10  67      0
   18    6     77      0
   19    5.2   88      1
```

What I would like is a percentage of the minority class I mention, slice the complete dataframe based on a particular column percentage. For ex: if I want the category percentage of the column to be 50:50 then my dataframe should contain 50% of samples with obese == 0 and 50% of the samples to be obese == 1, something like df_equal and so on for different percentages

Comment: What do you mean by *"and the slice of the dataframe to include that percentage of minority class for that column.*"? I answered the first part, but I just didn't get the second one.

Comment: Apologies If I could not potray it correctly but what I want to do is, slice the complete dataframe based on a particular column percentage. For ex: if I want the category percentage of the column to be 50:50 then my dataframe should contain 50% of samples with obese == 0 and 50% of the samples to be obese == 1, something like df_equal and so on for different percentages.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like is a percentage of the minority class I mention

```py
df['obese'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

will [return the relative frequencies of the unique values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).